# Windows Phone 8 apps being rejected in testing phase without justification

Tags: windows-phone-8, updates, marketplace

Is anyone aware of an issue pushing updates of WP8 apps to the marketplace?
All of my apps are being rejected and I don't get a reason why. The error report page states "Please address the comprehensive list of failures below and resubmit your updated application" but no list of failures is provided.

The same apps were approved 3 weeks ago without problems, and now they were rejected after minimal changes (new rating and feedback component ReviewMyApp added).

Help?

Comment: Without listing what the failure reasons were, we cannot speculate what happened. Attached to your rejection email should have been a pdf of the exact section(s) it failed under and the tester(s) reasons.

Comment: That's the thing caschw, there are no reasons listed. It's just empty. If there were reasons I could fix it, but there aren't. I'm wondering if it's because the app was compiled with the WP8 SDK and now it has to be compiled with the new WP8.1 SDK? A shot in the dark...

Comment: Resubmit or email support?

Comment: Same problem here. v1.0 was out without problems, v1.1 got rejected 3 times. I always try to check small things that COULD be the reason.. but still I seem not to get any feedback. Did you solve your problem?